# How to compute the limit of a function of two variables?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

In order to check if $$\;f(z) = \begin{cases}
{(\overline z)^2\over z} = {x^3-3xy^2 \over x^2 + y^2}+i{y^3-3x^2y \over x^2 + y^2}, & z \neq 0\\
0, &z=0
\end{cases}
$$ is differentiable at $z_0=0 \;$ I first need to check if it is continuous at $z_0=0$. To do this I need to compute the limits of both real an imaginary parts of the function and compare them to $f(0)=0$.

How do I compute, for instance the limit $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{x^3-3xy^2 \over x^2 + y^2}?$$

Comment: Same way  you do in calc 2?

Comment: @Batman taking limits along some paths?

Comment: a lot of theses are easier if you change to polar cords.

Comment: Well, you know that $\lvert \frac{\bar{z}^2}{z} \rvert = |z| \to 0$  so if it is continuous at $0$, it should be $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to polar coordinates i.e your limit for real part is:
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{r^3\cos^3\theta-3r^3\cos\theta \sin^2\theta}{r^2}=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\,\,  r(\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta \sin^2\theta)=0$$

Similarly, you can evaluate the limit for imaginary part.

Comment: Yes, I always forget about this powerful tool. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In exponential form: $f(z) = \frac{\overline z ^3}{|z|^2} = \overline z \frac{\overline z ^2}{|\overline z|^2} $, the second part being of module 1, it's easy to conclude. Very often in those problems, showing explicitly the module does the trick.

For the derivative, $\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z} = (\frac{\overline z}{z})^2$...